# Maximum number of sets in collection

Tags: combinatorics

Let V be a collection of $80$-element subsets of an $n$-element set such that the intersection cardinality of any two of them is $18,21,40, 56$. How to prove that the maximum number of sets in this collection does not exceed $ 1 + \frac{n(n + 1)}{2}$?

Comment: Do you mean that the cardinality of the intersection of any two of the subsets is one of those four numbers?

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly that

Comment: How far have you gotten with this?  Questions that are just problem statements, with no indication that the poster has made any attempt at solution run the risk of being closed.  (Personally, I have no idea how to do this problem.  I'm just trying to help you get an answer from someone who does.)

Comment: The fact of the matter is that I would be glad to any hint on the solution of this problem, since I am at a dead end, I do not understand at all how it can be solved. I just had a small idea related to matrices.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and add your small idea, even if it doesn't seem to lead anywhere.  It will get a much better reception.